# How to reorder/sort dataframe indexes with Pandas?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I got some data:

```
# 3 Experiments 0,1 and 2.
# 2 Setups 'foo' and 'bar'
# 3 Measured parameters 'a', 'b' and 'c'
d = {0: {'foo': {'a': 12.68, 'b': 54.44, 'c': 83.98},
         'bar': {'a': 11.73, 'b': 53.34, 'c': 82.93}},
     2: {'foo': {'a': 11.12, 'b': 57.99, 'c': 81.05},
         'bar': {'a': 10.05, 'b': 56.12, 'c': 80.01}},
     1: {'foo': {'a': 13.41, 'b': 54.32, 'c': 82.74},
         'bar': {'a': 12.77, 'b': 53.15, 'c': 82.01}}}
```

I imported them in Pandas

```
ds = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
      .stack().apply(pd.Series)
      .rename_axis(['experiment', 'setup']))
```

Which then is nicely displayed:

```
                      a      b      c
experiment setup
0          foo    12.68  54.44  83.98
           bar    11.73  53.34  82.93
2          foo    11.12  57.99  81.05
           bar    10.05  56.12  80.01
1          foo    13.41  54.32  82.74
           bar    12.77  53.15  82.01
```

You notice the experiments are in the wrong order and the setups are also not sorted. So I would like to sort the indexes to display it as follow:

```
                      a      b      c
experiment setup
0          bar    11.73  53.34  82.93
           foo    12.68  54.44  83.98
1          bar    12.77  53.15  82.01
           foo    13.41  54.32  82.74
2          bar    10.05  56.12  80.01
           foo    11.12  57.99  81.05
```

I tried many things using `sort`, `sort_index`, `sort_values` or even `sortlevel`, but I doesn't seem to work. I also tried to flatten everything using `reset_index` and tried again with `sort`, but it doesn't work.

How to sort or reorder a dataframe as wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very weird that `sort_index` doesn't work as expected but I managed to get the expected output by resetting index, sorting values and setting the index back:

```
ds = ds.reset_index()\
       .sort_values(by=['experiment','setup'])\
       .set_index(['experiment','setup'])
```

Comment: It seems that working on flat data is how Pandas is designed for